# Update MySQL data based on radio button

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing a challenge right now.

I have a return page, if I selected the first row via the radio button, I would like to change the **history_status** inside my **order history** table from `"DONE"` to `"RETURN PENDING"`. The reason why I am doing this is to run a query to show only **history_status** value with `"DONE"`.

Below are the code I am working with:

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','customercaremodule');
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
$FBdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$sql = "SELECT p.product_id ,p.product_name , p.price, p.product_description, o.history_id ,o.qty , o.subtotal, o.history_datetime , o.history_status FROM product p, orderhistory o where o.product_id = p.product_id AND o.history_status = 'DONE'";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);

$Cntsql = "SELECT count(return_id) AS total FROM retrn";
$res = mysqli_query($db,$Cntsql);
$value = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
$num = $value['total'];


if (isset($_POST['submitbuttonform']))
{

 $return_id = $num+1;
 $return_status = 'PENDING';
 $return_reason = $_POST['reasonselected'];
 $return_option = $_POST['returnoption'];
 $return_datetime = $FBdate;
 $history_id = $_POST['selectitemradio'];
 $history_status = "UPDATE orderhistory SET history_status = 'RETURN PENDING'";
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `retrn`(`return_id`, `return_status`, `return_reason`, `return_option`, `return_datetime`, `history_id`) VALUES ('$return_id','$return_status','$return_reason','$return_option','$return_datetime','$history_id')";
 $sql = "INSERT INTO 'orderhistory'('history_status') VALUES ('$history_status')";
 $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
```

[image]
[Order History Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni0Vd.png)

[image]
[Return page layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bt9ZN.png)

Comment: ```"UPDATE orderhistory SET history_status = 'RETURN PENDING'"``` this query updates all rows to 'RETURN PENDING', you need to put ```where``` clause to update only particular row. Also confirm, are you trying to store query in db? ```$history_status``` is used in ```INSERT``` query.

Comment: What if I only want the selected radio button to be updated to "RETURN PENDING?" What is the where clause statement I should write? @shashidhara

Answer (score 0):

From your code
$history_id = $_POST['selectitemradio']; I assume you get the history id from the page.

So you can use the history_id in the where clause. Now only the selected row will be updated.

> UPDATE orderhistory SET history_status = 'RETURN PENDING' where history_id=$history_id